# Optimal "Generalization" of Polylines

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, linear-programming

This question is inspired by a lossy compression technique for polylines, namely to identify a subset of the points of polyline $\mathcal{P}$, whose removal yields a polyline $\mathcal{Q}$ within a given Hausdorff distance of $\mathcal{P}$.
The primary objective of this "weeding" is to obtain $\mathcal{Q}$ with minimal number of points.
The most prominent heuristic is the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) and I do not know of any exact algorithm.

**Question:**
given a polyline $\mathcal{P}$ with $n>2$ points, is there an algorithm or formulation of the optimization problem, that yields among all polylines $\mathcal{Q}$ with $d_H\left(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q}\right)\le c$ one of those with a minimal number of points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper below is close to your question, but not exactly. I don't think your exact question has been answered in the literature. This paper finds the
optimal simplification under the Hausdorff measure for *monotone* polygonal chains. They get further with the Fréchet distance, without the monotone restriction. They also compare experimentally against Douglas-Peucker (DP below).

> P. K. Agarwal and S. Har-Peled and N. H. Mustafa and Y. Wang. Near-linear time
>   approximation algorithms for curve simplification. *Proc. of the 10th Annual European Symp. on Algorithms*, 29-41, 2005.
>   [PDF download](http://sarielhp.org/p/02/frechet_simp/frechetsimp.pdf).

---

[image: Simplifications]

---